# Android - How to open Activity by clicking button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onclick

How do I open an Activity(GameProcess) by clicking on a button(ButStart)?

I already edited it and take to manifest. What mistakes do you see? It crashes when I tap the button(ButStart).

```
package com.makeandroid.klikomania;

public class KlikomaniaActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button Butstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butstart);
    final Button Butrez = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butrez);

    Butstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(KlikomaniaActivity.this,GameProcess.class); 
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

}
```

And Here is GameProgress Activity:

```
package com.makeandroid.klikomania;


public class GameProcess extends Activity {



 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameprocess);

        }
 }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.makeandroid.klikomania"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.makeandroid.klikomania.GameProcess"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.makeandroid.klikomania.KlikomaniaActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is in logcat?

Comment: What happens? Does the app crash?

Comment: Hello, can you please share the whole Manifest? What is the exception message? Make also sure that you do not have error in XML resources.

Comment: there are no errors, it chrashes whe i tap the button

Comment: "no errors" - "crashes"?  Huh?

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: If there were no errors it would not crash ;)
I think the user is unaware of logging^^

Comment: i don't know what is longcat...ok if you don't understand my code, can you write transition from one activity to another by Button

Comment: You better learn how to use LogCat, don't go around the problem at hand, you will not learn anything from that

Comment: sorry i am not a professional programer, i begining with the Android, and search for help

Comment: here the same question but the answers don't help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093741/android-activities-startactivity

Comment: Is everything ok with your R.layout.gameprocess layout XML resource? Try to put a breakpoint in the onCreate() of GameProcess Activity and check in debug mode whether the breakpoint is reached. Besides turn on the LogCat view in Eclipse and check the Exception message.

Comment: Run `logcat` when your Emulator or test device is connected to your computer. Tap the button to invoke the crash and post the output from logcat here. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `button Butstart` is `null`. Check "butstart" id in your `main.xml`